# How to extract DDL from Oracle Data Pump dump file without importing?

Tags: database, oracle

I want to restore dump file backup but size of my file is about 300GB.

How can I extract DDL without importing to Oracle database. Because when I import it to Oracle database installed on Windows I get many errors.

The backup file is from Oracle 10g installed on CentOS.

Is that any way to convert heavy dump file to DDL directly?

If there is no way to convert, can I import that backup export from Linux server Oracle to my Windows Oracle?

Answer (score 3):

> #### SQLFILE
>
> **Purpose**
>   Specifies a file into which all of the SQL DDL that Import would have executed, based on other parameters, is written. For [More](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_import.htm)

**Syntax**

```
SQLFILE=[directory_object:]file_name
```

**Example**

```
impdp hr/hr DIRECTORY=dpump_dir1 DUMPFILE=expfull.dmp SQLFILE=dpump_dir2:expfull.sql
```

The Oracle Data Pump dump file is OS platform independent.